# VB.NET syntax for EditorFor template?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I tried to create my own templated helpers, but I got stuck on TextBoxFor syntax. In C# it's:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model) %>
```

And I cannot figure out (or google it) - how to write that in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like standard C# Lambda syntax, so the translation would be:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor( Function (model) model ) %>
```

Basically you are giving Html.TextBoxFor a function with 1 parameter. That function doesn't do anything, it just echos the argument back to the caller.

This would require VB 10, which is found in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Just one small detail - since it is a function, it should be declared as such - Funcion(model) model

Comment: Yep. I don't know what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to actually create the template first, but after it is created, you can use it like this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.YourField)%>
```